# lFacebook JS SDK - Event subscribe not working

Tags: events, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<script>
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('TEST');
    }
);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <fb:like send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" />
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on like, the alert is not showing up. I have tried the same code before and it seemed to work. Do you see something wrong? I don't see any errors in JS console...I am in localhost.

**EDIT**: 
Here you can see it live: http://jsfiddle.net/jCE5K/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/, you need to have a `fb-root` DIV tag.

Comment: Hi. I have already tried with the fb-root and is not working either. Actually the JS SDK adds automatically the fb-root in the DOM...

Comment: It used to not automatically add it.  I don't know when that changed.  Can you post your code in a jsfiddle that we can look at?

Comment: Updated. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: This is weird. This code: http://jsfiddle.net/nGfpn/ works in jsfiddle but not in a straight html file in my local...(notice that there is no fb-root div)

Comment: Nice to learn new things and to see the API is more forgiving than it was before!  Can you try adding FB.init() before the FB.Event.subscibe to see if that makes your code work on your page. I do know that the FB.init() call will require the fb-root div (I just tried it)

Comment: Have you tried the jsfiddle code in your local? http://jsfiddle.net/nGfpn/ ? I have tried with both fb-root and without it and is not working. Even though in jsfiddle is working (alert is being triggered)....

Comment: How do you mean my local?  Do you mean localhost?  If so, then that's your issue. The site has to be publicly accessible for the Facebook linter to lint it correctly for the subscribe event to fire.

Comment: DMCS. I have had the facebook like button and the listener working in a single html file in local for many weeks...

Comment: If it is, then your local is publicly accessible.  Otherwise it won't be able to lint the url to get the og meta data from it.

Comment: I can vouch that Hommer's code works localhost. And my localhost is definitely not "publicly accessible".